# Python object composition - accessing a method from the class that called it

Tags: python, oop, composition

You'll have to forgive me, I am trying to teach myself OO but I have come across this problem with composition and 'has-a' relationships.

```
class Main(object):
    def A(self):
        print 'Hello'
    def B(self):
        self.feature = DoSomething()

class DoSomething(object):
    def ModifyMain(self):
        #Not sure what goes here... something like
        Main.A()

def run():
    M = Main()
    M.B()
```

A real world example of the above simplification is a PySide application where Main is a MainWindow, and DoSomething is a dynamically created widget that is placed somewhere in the window. I would like DoSomething to be able to modify the status bar of the mainwindow, which is essentially calling (in Main) self.statusbar().

If there is a shortcut in PySide to do this, Tops!! please let me know! However, I'm actually after the more general Pythonic way to do this.

I think I'm close ... I just can't make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. At no time do you call `ModifyMain`; and
2. `Main.A()` will result in an error, because `A` is an instance method, but you are calling it on a *class*.

You want something like:

```
class Main(object):
    def A(self):
        print 'Hello'
    def B(self):
        self.feature = DoSomething() # self.feature is an instance of DoSomething
        self.feature.ModifyMain(self) # pass self to a method

class DoSomething(object):
    def ModifyMain(self, main): # note that self is *this* object; main is the object passed in, which was self in the caller
        #Note case - main, not Main
        main.A()

def run():
    M = Main()
    M.B()

if __name__=="__main__": # this will be true if this script is run from the shell OR pasted into the interpreter
    run()
```

Your names all flout the usual python conventions found in [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which is a pretty good guide to python style. I have left them as they were in your code, but don't copy the style in this example - follow PEP8.

Comment: Marked correct because it answers the general question asked ... am still interested if there is a more OOP way to do this

Comment: @jazzvibes In what sense is this not object-oriented?

Comment: my thoughts exactly ... until @teukkams' response

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a signal and slot instead? That's a more Qt and OOP way of doing this.

In your dynamically created widget class:

```
self.modifyMain = QtCore.Signal(str)
```

In your main class:

```
@QtCore.Slot(str)
def changeStatusbar(self, newmessage):
    statusBar().showMessage(newmessage)
```

in you main class after creating your widget:

```
doSomething.modifyMain.connect(self.changeStatusbar)
```

And in you widget class, where you want to change the statusbar of main, you say:

```
modifyMain.emit("Hello")
```

None of this is tested as I don't have a PySide installation handy.

Comment: almost -1 Vague, likely beyond the knowledge of a beginner.

Comment: What? He says he's using PySide, which is just the Python implementation of Qt4. Signals and slots are one of the most basic mechanics in any Qt application, regardless of the language it's implemented in.

Comment: The guy didn't realise that he wasn't even calling the method he wanted to call. You can't just drop in some keywords and expect them to be understood by a total beginner. Note that I didn't downvote you, because this answer is only unhelpful rather than wrong.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the signals/slots method, working from @Marcin's solution?

Comment: @Marcin chill, I'm not a complete beginner. I left the call to the method out mostly because its 1am...

Comment: Fair enough, I should have added example code right off the bat. Edited my answer.

Comment: @jazzvibes Although this isn't "more object-oriented" (it's just different), this is more appropriate to your described use-case (rather than your example code).

Comment: This is not much different or more OO like @Marcin says. It's just the Qt way of achieving loose coupling. In Marcin's example, the example are connected by passing a reference to main to the child widget. Here it's made by connecting the signal and slot.